# HIbernate level 2 cache

Tags: hibernate

Can we use HIbernate level 2 cache (query caching) without any external cache provider like EH cache? In other words, can we use in-memory caching for hibernate level 2 cache just like we have used in hibernate level 1 cache? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Infact there is one internal cache implementation provided by hibernate out of box called Hashtable, but it is not intended to be used in production.

See the explanation about second level cache below

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache